# order of multiple keys in \cite-command

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

The `biblatex`-command `\cite{key}` can take several keys, separated by a comma: `\cite{ckey1,akey2,bkey3}`.

The output is a list **ordered alphabetically by surname**: `akey2; bkey3; ckey1` (where `key` of course is a bibliographic item).

I wonder whether or not it is possible to control this feature, i.e., to decide somehow if the resulting list is ordered alphabetically or if the order of that list is as they appear within the brackets of `\cite`: `ckey1; akey2; bkey3` (which is useful if you want to retain that order or, e.g., want to list several bibliographic items chronologically).

(In case it is significant: I use `style=authortitle-icomp`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's controled by the `sortcites` option of `biblatex`. If enabled (it is for the style you are using), such cases are sorted by the **global** sorting scheme (package `sorting` option). By default, this is `nty` which is why you see them sorted by surname. If you don't want them sorted, as you say, set the global sorting scheme to `none`. You can always use the `sorting` option for `\printbibliography` should you want to specify a sorting scheme for your reference list(s).

Comment: does that mean that I have to decide globally how I want my citations ordered? So I cannot decide globally for `nty` and sometimes locally for `ynt`?

Comment: For citations, they always obey the global sorting scheme so you can't sort them differently in different places. That would be quite esoteric ... of course, sorting schemes can be quite complex and you can make your own (using Biber as the backend).